# Ubuntu wont find my wireless card pre-installed on my macbook pro

Tags: wireless

Whenever I try to run `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0` it does not show any wireless cards although there is one pre-install on my computer called 'AirPort utility'.

I tried using `sudo lshw -C network` and I've sent a picture showing what happened:

[image: screenshot showing terminal output]

Comment: Use `sudo lshw -C network` to see if the hardware is visible to your system.

Comment: I don't think this had any effect. I'm not sure how to send a screenshot to you

Comment: @KhyanTurton you can edit your own question to add an image. it will provide a way to upload it.

Comment: Broadcom wireless adapters don't work in monitor mode on Linux. So don't run `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0` :-)

Comment: how do I then get Ubuntu on VirtualBox to recognise my wireless adapter ?